# Insert text at a fixed position on each line in a text file

Tags: c#

I have a text file with a list of part numbers. I need to append the first part number of each line with a system number. 
Data looks like this:

> ```
> 94-CP1019011;967;94-EA1015590;1;
> 94-CP1019011;980;94-EA1020966;1;
> 94-CP1019011;669;94-EA1019084;1;
> 94-CP1019011;655;94-EA1015807;1;
> 94-CP1019011;326;94-KT1016113;1;
> 94-CP1019013;383;94-KT1015547;1;
> 94-CP1019013;608;94-MA1013256;1;
> 94-CP1019013;924;94-MA1019863;1;
> 94-CP1019013;384;94-MA1014969;1;
> ```

The first part number is always 12 char, so I have tried this:

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/Temp/BOM.txt");
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:/Temp/xBOM.txt");
for (;;)
{
    string s = reader.ReadLine();
    if (s == null)
        break;

    s = s.Insert(12, "-814590");
    writer.WriteLine(s);
}
```

For some reason it does not complete the entire file and preferably I would like it modify the one file rather than create a new one. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where are you closing or disposing the writer?

Comment: The loop is fine - it's a standard loop-and-a-half. The problem is outside the code you have posted. I suspect that you're not closing the file before trying to use it. Also, the only way to modify the original file in this way is to create a new one like you're doing, then delete the old one and rename the new one. Unless you can read it all into memory - see Hari Prasad's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem, need few changes.

You might call `continue`  instead of `break`. Modify

`if (s == null) break;`

to

```
if (s == null) continue;
```

Final code snippet should be...

```
while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
{
    string s = reader.ReadLine();
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) continue;

    s = s.Insert(0, "-814590");
    writer.WriteLine(s);
}
```

*If you are interested*, we can also do this using few `Linq` statements.

```
 var formattedLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:/Temp/BOM.txt")
                .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                .Select(s => s.Insert(12, "-814590")).ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:/Temp/xBOM.txt", formattedLines);
```

Comment: see   
@MatthewWatson  comment - this will loop forever :-)

Comment: The second part of your answer using Linq is good, but the first part does nothing substantially different from the OP's loop, which was fine as it is. However, note that you MUST call `ToArray()` or `ToList()` on the results of the `.Select()` if you were to change this to write back to the original file directly rather than a new file.

Comment: @K Wheddon You can use the Linq part of this answer to write back to the original file if your file fits into memory, but you will need to make two changes: (1) Add `.ToArray()` after the `.Select()`. (2) Change the filename in `File.WriteAllLines()` to the original filename.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewWatson for pointing the issue, corrected it now.

Comment: Hari Prasad thank you, your solution has given me the result I was looking for. @MatthewWatson thanks again for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your file for empty lines terminated with null, 
sometimes this is the issue when TextReader just stops read as it get null on line.

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/Temp/BOM.txt");
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:/Temp/xBOM.txt");

while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.ReadLine())) 
{
    string s = reader.ReadLine();

    s = s.Insert(12, "-814590");
    writer.WriteLine(s);
}

reader.Dispose();
writer.Close();
writer.Dispose();
```

Comment: That will loop forever when the end of the file is reached and `reader.ReadLine()` starts returning `null` each time it is called.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - true - will fix that

Comment: @MatthewWatson fixed.

Comment: Well now it's going to be throwing away alternate lines as it consumes them in the `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.ReadLine())`. Note that there's nothing wrong with the OP's code.

Comment: Thanks very much works as expected now. Also thanks @MatthewWatson for heads up on the loop.  I would still like to be able to do this within the same file, can it be done?

Comment: @profesor79 code snippet performing `ReadLine()` twice, you might want to correct it?

Comment: @KWheddon It's the file closing that fixes it I suspect. But the code above currently has a bug as I pointed out. Alternate lines are being skipped.

Comment: Yes it seems to be throwing away alternate lines didn't notice at first